# How to get error description from status callback from Twilio SMS?

Tags: java, callback, sms, twilio, webhooks

In case of `sent/delivered` status, Twilio is `POST`ing to the requested webhook url with the following parameters: `SmsSid, SmsStatus, MessageStatus, To, MessageSid, AccountSid, From, ApiVersion`)

I am not able to emulate a `failed/undelivered` status with a trial account.

And the docs [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) says:

> Twilio will POST the MessageSid along with the other standard request
>   parameters as well as MessageStatus and ErrorCode.

My question is from the `ErrorCode`(numeric) how do you get the "ErrorMessage"/"ErrorDescription", something which is human readable.

Does Twilio pass that in any of the params in case of `failed`/`undelivered` status?
I found the docs saying:

> If your message status is failed or undelivered, the ErrorCode can
>   give you more information about the failure.

But how? In form of any other extra params being passed by Twilio to our webhook url. If yes, what are the param name for them? Or a new api call using the `ErrorCode`?. How do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Human readable descriptions of the errors are available in the [error reference in the Twilio docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/reference).

The message delivery errors are the following:

> 30001: Message Delivery - Queue overflow
>
> 30002: Message Delivery - Account suspended
>
> 30003: Message Delivery - Unreachable destination handset
>
> 30004: Message Delivery - Message blocked
>
> 30005: Message Delivery - Unknown destination handset
>
> 30006: Message Delivery - Landline or unreachable carrier
>
> 30007: Message Delivery - Carrier violation
>
> 30008: Message Delivery - Unknown error

Hope this helps!

Comment: My question is: Is this "human readable message" passed as a param when Twilio `POST`s the status response to the configured webhook url. Or do I need to maintain this list in my application(which doesn't sound good)? Or is there any other way?

Comment: The docs say that only a `MessageStatus` and `ErrorCode` are sent. If you are considering using the "human readable error" to display to users then I wouldn't suggest that. I've edited the question with the message delivery errors, as you can see they are more useful for you as a developer or the Twilio support team than a user.

Comment: Yeah, the docs say about `MessageStatus` and `ErrorCode` only. Will create some kind of map for these 8 to 10 cases with user oriented description.

Comment: one follow up question here. If the provided webhook URL is down when Twilio is trying to `POST` to it, will Twilio retry after some time, or does it not retry at all. Is there a way to make it retry programmatically?
Any leads?

Comment: I have seen the Debugger, and its actually great, but I am more concerned if there is any API exposed to initiate the retry of status callback to the webhook?

Comment: Twilio will not retry, the webhooks were born out of real time control of phone calls in which retries don't make sense. In the case of not receiving a callback because your application was down, you could then poll the API to check on the status of a message.